# Email not being sent using Django send_mail()

Tags: django, django-forms, smtp

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
SMTP_PORT = 456
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_email@yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

the method:

```
def contact(*args,**kwargs):
    contactform = ContactForm(request.POST, prefix='contactform')
    send_mail(
        'Contact from website by '+contactform.name,
        contactform.message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['saxoya8501@emailhost99.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

It does not send any email. In the logs I get:

```
"GET /?contactform-name=myname&contactform-email=aaaa%40gnm.com&contactform-message=aaaaaaaaaaaaaa HTTP/1.1" 200 20808
```

The form that I am using is this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    prefix = 'contactform'

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'materialize-textarea'}))
```

Any suggestions on how to get it to work?

Comment: You're sending a GET request but using request.POST in your view

Comment: haha didn't realize that! It solved the problem. You can give it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue because of your Gmail security. Give permission in your gmail account settings to allow unsecure apps